# Java FileStore concept vs actual storage?

Tags: java, filesystems, partitioning, disk, volumes

How do Java [`FileStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) relates to other non Java concepts such as Device, Partition, File System, or Volume?

Not sure this is correct at all, especially when starting to read the definition:

> **public abstract class FileStore**
>
> Storage for files. A FileStore represents a storage pool, device,
>   partition, volume, concrete file system or other implementation
>   specific means of file storage.

Comment: I can't see what is your assessment of the non clarity of "How do these concepts relate to each other, from a Java developer standpoint" Nevertheless, I'll split the question in two, keeping only FileStore concept here (because a the existing answer with adresses only this scope), and opening a new one for understanding the relationship between other concepts. You may block again the latter if necessary, and explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's more abstract than that.  A FileStore is

> The FileStore for where a file is stored is obtained by invoking the getFileStore method, or all file stores can be enumerated by invoking the getFileStores method.

i.e. it is any store where you can get the contents of a file by name or list all the files.

There is a built in implementation for the file systems e.g. a drive, but there is also one for ZIP/JAR files.  You could write one for a FTP service.

An in memory version would be a `Map<String, FileContents>` where you can look up content or get a list of names.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good addition. Your clarification leads me to move the question about relationship between other concepts (which are not Java specific) to a new topic.